# Reuse chosen dropdown field value on frontend

Tags: variable, frontend, drop-down, set

I would like to choose entry values from a frontend dropdown and reuse the chosen value directly.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mountainbikes') %}

<select name="year">
{% for entry in entries %}
  <option value={{ entry.year }}>{{ entry.year }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

How can i get the chosen value and reuse it in the same template?
For example:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
  {% if entry.year == '2015' %} /* chosen value in dropdown field */
    {{ entry.title }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use the chosen value elsewhere in the template on the same request? i.e. without hitting a submit button somewhere and using it on another page.

Comment: Actually, yes - on the same request. I would like to build a little suspension setup calculator, where i'd like to choose the bike first by year and second by modell (Both are field entries). Then put out the appropriate setup values.

Comment: If you want to do that without making a request to the server, you'll need to use JavaScript to retrieve the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've got now a working approach to my question above:

```
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('jahrgang') %}

<form action="tourdefrance.html" method="post">
   <select class="dropdown" name="modelljahr" size="1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
     {% for opt in field.settings.options %}
        <option name="fields[myFieldHandle][]" value="{{ opt.value }}">{{ opt.value }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
   </select>

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mountainbikes') %}

{% set modelljahr = craft.request.getParam('modelljahr') %}

<form action="tourdefrance.html" method="post">
  <select class="dropdown" name="modell" size="1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    {% for entry in entries %}
      {% if entry.jahrgang == modelljahr %}
        <option value="{{ entry.title }}">{{ entry.title }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

{{ craft.request.getParam('modell') }}
```